# Which test-methods are right for my data?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, excel, fishers-exact-test

I'm writing my final thesis in Chinese Studies right now and planned on doing a qualitative test but as I have so much data I would like to analyse it quantitatively. I did so but am not sure about the **test-methods** - can you help me?

Here is what I did: I'm analysing the design differences between a) English and Chinese  and b) German and Chinese versions of websites. I have 50 Chinese, 47 English and 37 German versions. I am trying to **test if the differences found are significant**. Am I doing it right?

[Here are some screenshots from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYihi.jpg).

1. `Yes/No` questions: Some criteria just ask if a site does have something or not (like Internet Explorer 6 (IE6) compatibility). What I get is:

   ```
   30 x Yes; 20 x No - for Chinese version
   15 x Yes; 22 x No - for German version
   17 x Yes; 30 x No - for English version
   ```

   Can I use the **Chi-square-test** for that kind of data? As I might split the data into genres I might end up with quite small datasets. Is the **exact Fisher's test** better? (see screenshots in link).
2. Values `0, 1, 2, 3`: I'm also analysing things like visibility of social media buttons (0=not visible, 3=very visible). In order to find out significant differences in the average can I take the **t-Test**? As only one side is important (does Chinese version get a higher number?) do I take the one-sided test or two-sided test? Excel also asks me if the data is paired, if I have the same variances or different variances - what does that mean? (see screenshots in link above for my results).
3. And finally I got data for the width and height of websites. Can I also use a **t-test** to analyse the data?  I did a **Box plot/box and Whiskers Chart** but am not sure what it does for me besides giving me a quick overview - or can I also see significant differences with it? (see screenshots in link for the charts - the one does seem to have differences the other one not.)

Please help me by telling me if the used test-methods are right and confirm that I can use them or not. By the way I analyse all the data in Excel as I have no experience with any other tools (and for my major something like this isn't required at all but I would like to do it anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sound like paired data, since you've accessed different language versions of the same sites. Paired sites mean that the presence or absence of some item in one language version of one site is more closely related to presence or absence of that same item in the same version of the site but for a different language. To account for data of that structure, you need to think about paired categorical analysis.

The [McNemar's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) extends the direct analogues of Pearson's Chi Square and Fishers Exact Tests of 2x2 contingency table data. The basic null hypothesis remains the same: is frequency of site features equal between language versions? However, you can show mathematically that the McNemar's test conditions upon unmeasured sources of variation in which types of sites may be more or less likely to host certain services, such as public interest vs. social network vs. broadcast media.

Similarly, for pseudocontinuously valued data such as in your question 2, you can use the paired t-test as an extension of the regular t-test. To address your question about variance specification, I always specify my variances as unequal at the cost of a modest loss of power, but with the reward of a great deal of validity. However, the paired t-test makes this assumption unnecessary because we treat the differences between groups as a single random variable and avoid modeling between cluster effects.

Again, testing for differences in dimensions involves quantifying some continuous value and testing its difference using paired analyses. Your box-whiskers do not indicate what value you've measured, but let me suggest you consider the diagonal, as screens are measured, given in pixels as an outcome.

Comment: Let me see if I got it right:

As the data is connected (same website but different language version) the Pearson's Chi Square and Fisher's Exact Test do still work but the McNemar's Test gives an advantage regarding further conclusions, right?

Regarding the T-Test I can simply use the one-sided paired test and should be fine. This seems to work fine for the data where the values are 0, 1, 2, 3 but looking at the width and height of websites in px I somehow don't understand the results as they seem to be the opposite of what I would expect the results to be: http://i.imgur.com/n1oqwNdh.png

Comment: Your assertions about McNemar's vs Pearson's/Fisher's are exactly correct. More power, better inference, better estimation from accounting for correlation. I've not actually viewed these sites, but regarding your "prior beliefs" about the distribution of screen dimensions, perhaps you should consider a two-tailed test and think about the meaning of the results and what null hypothesis testing really tells you! I cannot actually infer what the exact test statistics are from this analysis, so you will have to error check your own work if that's what you're asserting.

Comment: At the very least, the sign of inference should always match the mean difference in the two groups. If it is otherwise, then you've computed the test statistic incorrectly.

Comment: Okay - I think I got it now. Thank you very much for your quick help. And yes the two-tailed test does make more sense in this case, also the results seem to agree. I marked your answer as accepted. :)